# react-native-text-recognition is not functioning correctly and throwing issue of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application in which a user can select an image from his or her image gallery. Once they select an image, they have the option to extract the text from that image. I am currently using `react-native-text-recognition` as the package to extract the information. I installed `react-native-text-recognition` and I am incorporating it into a function that make sure an image uri is selected. I am getting the following error which makes no sense:

```
 LOG  react native text recognition: {"recognize": [Function recognize]}
 LOG  preprocessed image:  file:///Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB8866C8-D53D-47DA-99F2-5CD700EF4EE1/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC734A7E-06AB-4D6E-A078-AAE568879878/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FIOweYou-6d1646a9-9f6c-418d-9753-3ce4dce5140a/ImageManipulator/0474D866-A1EC-4387-9393-6335F6DA535A.jpg
 LOG  call inside if:  {"recognize": [Function recognize]}
 ERROR  Text recognition error: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'recognize' of null]
```

Here is my current functions code:

```
const performOCR = () => {
    console.log('react native text recognition:', TextRecognition);
    console.log('preprocessed image: ', preprocessedImage);

    if (preprocessedImage && TextRecognition) {
      console.log('call inside if: ', TextRecognition);
      TextRecognition?.recognize(preprocessedImage)
        .then(result => {
          setOcrResult(result.text);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Text recognition error:', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('text recognition is not initialized');
    }
  };
```

The part that is confusing me is that both of the console.logs for TextRecognition show that there is something there with a recognize method attached to it. When I try to call the method with an image... It says that it is null. How on earth is this possible.

`console.log('call inside if: ', TextRecognition);` => `react native text recognition: {"recognize": [Function recognize]}`

when I use it:

`TextRecognition?.recognize(preprocessedImage)` =>  `ERROR  Text recognition error: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'recognize' of null]`

I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Check https://github.com/JoeyEamigh/react-native-text-recognition/issues/10

Comment: I tried that solution but got nothing. I will try again @James

Comment: the solution that was shown was for android but my issue is with iOS